# How is Daniel 12.2 accurately Translated?

Tags: translation-philosophy, daniel

Basically Daniel 12.2 has been translated as "and some to shame [and] everlasting contempt" particularly in the KJV and others. But I have also come across others reading: "and some to the shame of everlasting contempt" or "and some to shame, to everlasting contempt".

So I'm wondering which would present a more accurate translation (if any)? Or, how would you translate it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**: "and some to shame, to everlasting contempt" is probably the most accurate of all.

The verse in hebrew reads: ל-חרפות ל-דראון עולם. The hebrew letter *lamed* is used as a prefix and means "to". Being that "חרפות=shame" and "דראון עולם=everlasting shame/contempt" both contain the prefix "lamed=to" the most literal translation would render something like the one above. The first translation that chose the word [and] in place of "to" is also very much on mark, for one it definitely makes the words flows better and works very well with the hebrew grammatical rules.

The translation of "shame of everlasting contempt" is definitely the most creative of the three; instead of taking them as different expressions of shame (as the other two translations take it) it chooses to connect both words and mold it into "a shame of everlasting contempt", which though not the most simple reading of the text is still allowed by hebrew standards and is quite conceivable.

Answer (score 0):

Young's Literal Translation renders Dan. 12:2 as,

> "And the multitude of those sleeping in the dust of the ground do awake, some to life age-during, and some to reproaches -- to abhorrence age-during."

The second phrase emphasizes the level of reproach or shame. It would not be a mild shame, but one of complete abhorrence.

Answer (score 0):

Behold, I come as a thief. Blessed is he that watcheth, and keepeth his garments, lest he walk naked, and they see his shame.
Revelation 16:15 KJV
https://bible.com/bible/1/rev.16.15.KJV

And compare the parables in Matthew 24 and 25. All seem to point for a need to prepare.

Maybe it best to understand  it this way. This shame is associated with garments/ preparation.  What made Adam and Eve know that they were naked? Something must have disappeared. Why make an effort to cover themselves and yet still feel inadequate to stand before the Lord? And they cover them with skins of animals (?sheep).

What is man, that thou art mindful of him? and the son of man, that thou visitest him?  For thou hast made him a little lower than the angels, and hast crowned him with glory and honour.
Psalms 8:4‭-‬5 KJV
https://bible.com/bible/1/psa.8.4-5.KJV

This  glory is robes of light.
Who coverest thyself with light as with a garment: who stretchest out the heavens like a curtain:
Psalms 104:2 KJV
https://bible.com/bible/1/psa.104.2.KJV

Remember "let us make man in our image and our likeness"

So yes some will wake up and shine, judged and deemed worthy;
and some will wake up and find that they have no garments(righteousness).  Judged and deemed not worthy to enter into eternity. 
So to shame, realising that they have no garments; and everlasting contempt (hellfire complete eradication of their existence).

For, behold, the day cometh, that shall burn as an oven; and all the proud, yea, and all that do wickedly, shall be stubble: and the day that cometh shall burn them up, saith the Lord of hosts, that it shall leave them neither root nor branch.  And ye shall tread down the wicked; for they shall be ashes under the soles of your feet in the day that I shall do this, saith the Lord of hosts.
Malachi 4:1‭, ‬3 KJV
https://bible.com/bible/1/mal.4.1-3.KJV